# Late 90's Audi LCD Font

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm looking for a font that has the same look as the late 90s early 2000s Audi LCD displays. The closest match I have found is [Register Font](https://www.dafont.com/register.font) but the spacing between "pixels" is too big. Thank you in advance :)[image: Late 90s Audi LCD Display]:

Comment: You could fill in the gap by adding a stroke to the letters to make each pixel a little bolder. Or there's another one called  "LED Calculator" which has closer pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very basic pixel font. You could actually make one yourself or simply hand pixel the sentences you need.

Searching dafont.com in the [Bitmap](https://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php?text=PRESS+CLUTCH+PEDAL+TO+START+ENGINE&fpp=200) category yields many close matches.

One of them is [Enter Command](https://www.dafont.com/enter-command.font?fpp=200&text=PRESS+CLUTCH+PEDAL+TO+START+ENGINE).

[image]

The G and the D are a little bit different though. There might be a better match somewhere among the hundreds of bitmap fonts.

Most of the pixel fonts have no gap between the pixels. You can easily make that yourself by adding some kind of grid on top. The method depends on which program you use and what you need it for.

In Photoshop, with a grid on top, some glow on the letters, some gradients, some noise and a slightly distorted perspective you should be able to copy that LCD look:

[image]